# Laravel passport Authorization token expire on generating new token

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am using laravel 5.5 with passport authentication for API Routes. I am using bearer token. 
The problem is that the old generated token is accepted in place of unauthenticated.
Steps :

- create one bearer token. Use it. It is working fine.
- create another token without logout and it is working fine.
- now if I use the first created token it is also working. It should not be working but it is accepted.

Is there any way by what I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is:
Check before creating a new token, if an old one is existing and delete this one. To do this:

Create a Model named *OauthAccessToken*

Update your User Model the following

```
/**
 * 1:n zu access token, we need to logout users
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function accessTokens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OauthAccessToken::class);
}
```

Now you can check with this and delete all tokens from a user

```
if ($user->accessTokens->count() > 0) {
    $user->accessTokens()->delete();
}
```

Comment: Hi Matz thanks. I got this and removed token from 'oauth_access_tokens'. It is working fine. Can't we achieve this by refreshing tokens?